# getting error while adding some components from nuget in xamarin.android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget

Getting error while adding some nuget packages to xamarin.android project.

**Error-**

Could not install package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads 42.1021.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

[image]

Comment: Which Android API level does your project target?

Comment: Android 6.0 Marshmallow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest GooglePlayServices packages need Android 7 and above. In order for you to use in Android 6, you will need to use older packages.

Or you can just update the target platform to v7 and above.